# Quicker Way to Do This Than memcpy?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy

I use a SPI port to shift out some configuration data (stored in a struct) to some ASICs. I have one "active" struct which contains the next config to be shifted, but the actual config can be any of a dozen different configs that are stored in an array of structs. Currently, I'm using memcpy to actually copy the config struct from the array to the "active" SPI buffer location. Problem is, it's pretty slow, and as I do this over and over again the delay starts to add up. I have to do three copies each time for reasons related to daisy-chaining of my ASICs.

Seems like there should be an easy way to do this faster by setting the "active" struct to point to the correct stored struct, but I'm struggling to find it. Is the only way to do it by making g_spi4_config_buf actually just become a pointer to another pointer?

Code currently looks like this:

```
    if(x < 10)                                                //Lower third
    {
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx2, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone0].rx2, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx2));       
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx1, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone1].rx1, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx1));
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx0, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone2].rx0, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx0));
    }
    else if(x >= 10) && (x < 20)            //Middle third
    {
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx2, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone3].rx2, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx2));
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx1, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone4].rx1, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx1));
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx0, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone5].rx0, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx0));
    }
    else                                             //Upper third
    {
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx2, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone6].rx2, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx2));
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx1, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone7].rx1, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx1));
      memcpy((u8*)&g_spi4_config_buf.rx0, (u8*)&g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone8].rx0, sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx0));
    }
```

Comment: First off, those `(u8*)` casts aren't necessary.

Comment: Is the data in `g_spi4_zone_config_buf[]` constant or unchanged while the data is being sent over the API link?

Comment: I am assuming (because you are using `sizeof(g_spi4_config_buf.rx2)` ), that the struct member is defined such that when using `sizeof()` you will get more than just sizeof(char *);

Comment: Show the definition of `g_spi4_config_buf` and `g_spi4_zone_config_buf` (including definitions of any structs involved)

Comment: What is a typical value for `sizeof(g_spi_config_buf.rx2)`?  What exactly is `x` counting?  And why do you need to do the same exact copy 10 times (assuming that `x` is counting by 1)?

Comment: Please show some code on the back side that is using the g_spi4_config_buf.rx2 array.  It sounds like the g_spi4_zone_config_buf structures all contain constant data (that wouldn't be changing while the user of g_spi4_config_buf is processing?  Given that it seems likely that g_spi4_config_buf.rx0-2 could simply be defined as pointers such that: g_spi4_config_buf.rx2 = g_spi4_zone_config_buf[Zone0].rx2; sould simply be a pointer store and the usage on the backend wouldn't change...but without more detail I can't be sure.